# Azure Build Pipeline can't publish artifacts

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

**Error in Build Pipeline**

[image: Publish artifacts]

**Setup:**

[image]

**Previous Archieving stage.**

[image: Build Pipe Line]

**Setup :**

[image: archieve setup]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `/drop` from the `Path to publish`, just give the artifacts folder:

```
$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

Because you don't create a `drop` folder in the previous steps, you just put there a zip file.

Comment: Thanks @Shayki Abramczyk for your answer. It worked. marked as answer.